# Как правильно прочитать файл csv?

Tags: c#, консоль, csv

Есть класс где считывает переменные:

```
    [Serializable]
public class Class1
{
    [CsvColumn(Name = "1", FieldIndex = 1)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(Name = "0", FieldIndex = 2)]
    public string Parent { get; set; }

    [CsvColumn(Name = "aaa", FieldIndex = 3)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

и сама главная программа где все это выводит:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadCsvFile();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    private static void ReadCsvFile()
    {
        var csvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
            IgnoreUnknownColumns = true,
            SeparatorChar = ';',
            UseFieldIndexForReadingData = false
        };
        var csvContext = new CsvContext();
        var document = csvContext.Read<Class1>("Документ.csv", csvFileDescription);

        foreach (var files in document)
        {
            if (files.Parent == "0")
                Console.WriteLine($"{int.Parse(files.ID)} | {int.Parse(files.Parent)} | {files.Text.TrimStart()} ' - это корневой элемент'");
            else
            if (files.Parent != "0")
                Console.WriteLine($"{int.Parse(files.ID)} | {int.Parse(files.Parent)} | {files.Text.TrimStart()} ' - это дочерний элемент'");
        }
```

и есть задание, по которому я должен это сделать, в самом заголовке не поместилось - поэтому пишу здесь:
В исходном наборе данных, к примеру, CSV файл, содержатся данные, разбитые по трем колонкам:

Id - идентификатор родительского элемента

Parent - ссылка на родительский элемент

Text - произвольный текст

Id; Parent; Text

Если Parent = 0 то этот элемент является корневым, в противном случае элемент у которого Parent не 0 является дочерним.

Пример корневого элемента:

5;0;aaa

Пример дочернего элемента:

2;5;жжж

Вложенность дочерних элементов произвольна, то есть, к примеру:

5;0;aaa

2;5;жжж

1;2;ббб

Первая строка (Id = 5) - корневой элемент

Вторая строка (Id = 2) - дочерний элемент первой строки

Третья строка (Id = 1) - дочерний элемент второй строки

Необходимо написать программу, которая будет выводить все элементы из предоставленного списка, в виде дерева.

Количество элементов и вложенность ветвей дерева может быть произвольной.

К пирмеру, последовательность из указанных выше строк на выходе должна получить вид:

5;0;aaa

2;5;жжж

```
 1;2;ббб
```

Также, необходимо выполнить сортировку внутри каждой группы элементов.
вот сам результат того что я сделал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
я сделал только само чтение файла

но я сделал что смог подскажите как мне сделать сравнение Parent одной строки с ID в каждой строке, допустим строка где текст zead там он не входит в дерево так как Parent = 20 а ID нету с 20 номером и в следствии этого должно вывести сообщение что оно не входит в дерево и плюс сделать само дерево с отступом.
Заранее спасибо за предоставленную помощь!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмем класс

```
public class Class1
{   
    public string ID { get; set; }  
    public string Parent { get; set; }  
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

заполним

```
var classes = new[] {
        new Class1(){ID ="1", Parent = "2", Text = "t1"},
        new Class1(){ID ="2", Parent = "3", Text = "t2"},
        new Class1(){ID ="3", Parent = "5", Text = "t3"},
        new Class1(){ID ="4", Parent = "1", Text = "t4"},
    };
```

Добавим все айдишники в хешет

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var c in classes) set.Add(c.ID);
```

Выпишем классы, у которых родитель не нашёлся

```
foreach (var c in classes)
    if (!set.Contains(c.Parent)) 
        Console.WriteLine($"У {c.ID}-{c.Text} парент {c.Parent} не нашелся!");
```

Результат

```
У 3-t3 парент 5 не нашелся!
```

---

Теперь более сложный пример

```
var classes = new[] {
        new Class1(){ID ="1", Parent = "2", Text = "t1"},
        new Class1(){ID ="2", Parent = "4", Text = "t2"},
        new Class1(){ID ="3", Parent = "15", Text = "t3"},
        new Class1(){ID ="4", Parent = "0", Text = "t4"},
        new Class1(){ID ="5", Parent = "4", Text = "t5"},
        new Class1(){ID ="6", Parent = "4", Text = "t6"},
        new Class1(){ID ="7", Parent = "4", Text = "t7"},
    };
```

в этот раз примем, что `Parent="0"` означает корневой узел и добавит его сразу в хешсет

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
set.Add("0");

foreach(var c in classes) set.Add(c.ID);

foreach (var c in classes)
    if (!set.Contains(c.Parent)) Console.WriteLine($"У {c.ID}-{c.Text} парент {c.Parent} не нашелся!");
```

Далее, построим словарь, где ключ - это ид родителя, а значение - список дочерних узлов. Добавим словарь и заполним

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Class1>>();
foreach (var c in classes)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(c.Parent)) dict[c.Parent] = new List<Class1>();
    dict[c.Parent].Add(c);
}
```

Вывод узлов сделаем самописным методом

```
PrintNodes(dict, "0");
```

Сам метод использует рекурсию. Так как в задаче говорится о дереве - значит не ожидается никаких циклов в нем, тогда рекурсивный вывод сработает. Но если будут в данных циклы - то вся программа упадет.

Если хотите разобраться, как этот метод работает - гуглите "обход дерева в глубину"

```
private static void PrintNodes(Dictionary<string, List<Class1>> dict, string currentParent, string tab = ""){
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(currentParent)) return;
    foreach (var node in dict[currentParent].OrderBy(x=>x.Text))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{tab}Node:{node.ID}, {node.Text}, Parent:{node.Parent}");
        PrintNodes(dict, node.ID, tab + "    ");
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
У 3-t3 парент 15 не нашелся!
Node:4, t4, Parent:0
    Node:2, t2, Parent:4
        Node:1, t1, Parent:2
    Node:5, t5, Parent:4
    Node:6, t6, Parent:4
    Node:7, t7, Parent:4
```

Comment: это все хорошо но вот только ты генерируешь данные а я вывожу уже готовые с файла csv и тут у меня вопрос как с этим все проводить?

Comment: 1) читаешь сначала данные из файла
2) потом запускаешь код, все, что после генерации

Comment: ты не можешь сказать, какие паренты не найдены в момент, когда ты ещё весь файл не прочитал

Comment: так а как присвоить данные с файла в массив?

Comment: ну замени мое `foreach (var c in classes)` на твое `foreach (var files in document)`

Comment: спасибо советом то котел мой не варит и подскажи как мне сортировку сделать по полю text я только знаю как в sql это сделать можно

Comment: Если мой ответ помог - то галочка слева от ответа. А про сортировку в вопросе ничего нет. Ну можно `foreach (var files in document.OrderBy(x=>x.Text))` но вообще это отдельным вопросом надо тогда с пояснением

Comment: Вам надо научиться задавать вопросы. Вы то одно просите, то другое, то третье. Я переписал для вас пример с выводом в виде дерева и сортировкой узлов при выводе, но даавайте все новые вопросы задавайте отдельно уже.

Comment: @vlad_12 один пост - один вопрос, при появлении новых вопросов их действительно стоит задавать отдельно, а не в комментариях к ответу.